# dot tool doubles arrows

Tags: cluster-computing, graphviz, dot, subgraph

I've recently been using dot to create flow- and callgraphs of a rather complex assembly program. All in all this works perfectly fine, with just a little hickup. Sometimes, when drawing a line from one node inside a cluster to another node in a different cluster, the line somehow doubles.

I've added a stripped down version of my problem as code and a dot output image.

Thanks

```
digraph G {

  ratio=auto; node[fontsize=12]; label="boot"; newrank=true;

  {  
    node[shape=plaintext];
    1->2[arrowsize=0.7,penwidth=0.1];
  }

  Reset->uart_init[arrowsize=0.7, penwidth=0.1];

  { rank=same; "Reset"; "1"; }
  { rank=same; "uart_init"; "2"; }

  /* terminalhooks cluster */
  subgraph cluster42 {
    fontsize=12;
    label="terminalhooks.asm";
    labelloc=b;  
    type->emit[arrowsize=0.7,penwidth=0.1];
    emit[label=<emit<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">Terminal redirection hooks<BR/>für eventuelle Umleitungen</FONT>>];
  }

  /* stm-terminal cluster */  
  subgraph cluster43 {
    fontsize=12;
    label="stm-terminal.asm";
    labelloc=b;  
    emit->serial_emit->serial_qemit[arrowsize=0.7,penwidth=0.1];
    serial_emit[label=<serial_emit<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">Ausgabe Char via UART</FONT>>];
    serial_qemit[label=<serial_qemit<BR/><FONT POINT-SIZE="8">Prüft TXE (Transmit Buffer Empty)</FONT>>];
  }
  { rank=same; "type"; "emit"; "serial_emit"; "serial_qemit"; } 
}
```

[dot graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5CR4.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this happening, but adding `tailport=e` seems to fix it:

```
 emit->serial_emit->serial_qemit[tailport=e,arrowsize=0.7,penwidth=0.1];
 #                          -----^-----
```

## Edit:

It appears the `newrank` atr causing the problem.

```
digraph G {
  newrank=true;
  subgraph cluster42 {
        0;
        1; 
        0->1;
  }     
  subgraph cluster43 {
        2;
        3; 
        1->2->3;
  }     
  { rank=same; 0; 1; 2; 3; }
}
```

produce:

[image: pic1]

but if you remove:

```
  newrank=true;
```

it produce:

[image: pic2]

## Edit 2:

For this example you can use `rankdir=LR` and remove the `rank=same`:

```
digraph G {
  rankdir=LR;
  subgraph cluster42 {
        0; 
        1; 
        0->1;
  }     
  subgraph cluster43 {
        2; 
        3; 
        1->2->3;
  }
}
```

[image: pic3]

maybe you can do same with your complex graph too.

Comment: For some reason it works with my example, although it screws up the arrows quite a bit. But with a couple of other graphs adding tailport=e even adds another line...

Comment: You're right, newrank is causing it. The thing is I use ranks and clusters to show capsulation of assembler files... Without newrank the box around the functions doesn't show which makes interpreting the graph way harder.